# Is enum part of the Alloy language?

Tags: alloy

There is no mention of `enum` in the book Software Abstractions.

I have seen people use `enum` in Alloy models, so apparently it is supported by the Alloy tool.

I am guessing that in an old version of Alloy the `enum` keyword was part of the language and the code that supported `enum` has endured, despite `enum` being removed from the language. Do I guess correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's the opposite: enum was added to the language after the book was published.

Answer (score 3):

These are the features added after the book was published. They are all extremely useful.

- `seq` – lists. Unfortunately they are missing a literal which makes them a tad hard to use.
- `let` – macros that can be used outside predicates, functions or facts. Very useful for constants and other small functions. Do not require types which makes them easier to read but error reporting is dismal.
- `meta` – The possibility to access fields and types in a spec. Extremely nice if you're into reflection. Should be avoided by beginners.
- `private` – Private namespace, very useful for larger specs.
- `unsat` – Allows you to debug a spec when there is no solution. Promotes the use of small facts instead of grouping.

These new features are described in the [quick guide](http://alloytools.org/quickguide/)